# PHP rename() not working

Tags: php, wordpress, rename

I am trying to rename a duplicate file name upon upload of a new file with the same name.  Everything is working great except for that I am getting an error:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  rename(./uploads/484360_438365932885330_1444746206_n.jpeg,): No such file or directory in <b>/home/unisharesadmin/public_html/wp-content/themes/blankslate/check_duplicate_img.php</b> on line <b>36</b><br />
```

Despite confirming that the directory exists and that the file and directory are both writeable, PHP is still throwing this error.  I have consulted countless threads on here already and none of them seem to help, as I cannot find any path or string error with my file path.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Cheers
Colin

Code:

```
<?
require_once('../../../wp-config.php');

function RandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

$this_img = $_REQUEST['filename'];

$path = './uploads/' . $this_img;

$img_array = explode(".", $this_img);

$new_img = RandomString() . '.' . $img_array[sizeof($img_array)-1];

$new_path = './uploads/' . $new_img;

if (file_exists($path))
{
    query_posts('posts_per_page=-1');

    while(have_posts())
    {
      the_post();

      if( strpos(get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'imgurl1')[0], $this_img) !== false )  
      {
        //echo "this posts url1 matches, so update the existing files name and the posts refrence to it";
        echo is_writeable("./uploads");
        rename($path, $newpath);
        //echo update_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'imgurl1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/uploads/' . $new_img);

      }
      else if( strpos(get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'imgurl2')[0], $this_img) !== false )  //this posts url2 matches
      {
        echo "this posts url2 matches, so update the existing files name and the posts refrence to it";

        //rename($path, $newpath);
        //echo update_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'imgurl2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/uploads/' . $new_img);

      }

    }
}
else
{
 echo 0; 
}

?>
```

Comment: So where is the food? I mean the code?

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari just had to quickly reformat the code.  Please see my updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - The [rename](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function requires, at least, **two** arguments. It seems that you're providing just `one`.

2 - Also, you may want to use the full path, i.e.:

```
$path = '/full/path/to/uploads';
$new_path = '/full/path/to/uploads';
rename("$path/484360_438365932885330_1444746206_n.jpeg", "$new_path/newfile.jpeg");
```

3 - Make sure `$new_img` is set, your problem may be here:

```
$new_img = RandomString() . '.' . $img_array[sizeof($img_array)-1];
```

4 - Try setting a temporary hardcored valued to  `$new_img` and see if works, if it does, your error is there.

```
$new_img = "tempfile.jpeg";
```

---

**TIP:**
Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Remove in production.

Comment: Yes, but the error doesn't show that, that's why the problem must be  related with `$new_img`

Comment: I expect, he need to use full path. I checked his other codes and It is fine.   His php file location is */home/unisharesadmin/public_html/wp-content/themes/blankslate/check_duplicate_img.php*. @Pedro

Comment: @PedroLobito Hi, thanks for your comment. First, I am supplying two arguments since $path and $newpath are both string.  Second, I tried using a full path with no avail.  I tried using both a URL path and the server path.  Third, $newpath won't exist until the rename happens since it is the new file name. Finally, adding the hardcoded value does not work either.

Comment: Did you enable `error_reporting` ? Any meaningful output ?

Comment: @PedroLobito Thank you for the tip, enabling error reporting made me see my very stupid mistake of forgetting to include an underscore on $new_path in rename.  Dont I feel silly!  Thanks again mate.